# android listview: the first item gets highlighted automatically and i am unable to un highlight the first item of the list view

Tags: android, listview

i want multiple items to be selected,and highlighted ,this part works as expected but the problem is the first item also gets highlighted and i don't want it to happen .

The first item gets highlighted automatically and i am unable to un-highlight it even though i can highlight and un-highlight the rest of the items

here is how i am trying to highlight

```
    SngList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                                    @Override
                                    public void onItemClick(

                                            AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {

                                        highlight();                                            
                                    }

                                    private void highlight() {

//                                      if      (SngList.isItemChecked(0))
//                                      {   SngList.setItemChecked(position, false);
//                                      ab.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                                      
//                                      }
//                                      
                                        {   SngList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                                        ab.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        return;
                                        }
                                        // else if (SngList.isItemChecked(position))

                                            //{SngList.setItemChecked(position, false );
                                            //ab.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                            //}

                                    }});
```

and then in the getview method i am changing the color by

```
 if(list.isItemChecked(position)){
           v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#239700"));
        }
        else{
              v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
```

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: as described by my question,there are unusual things happening which i don't want

Comment: What is that thing? Elaborate more

Comment: use a tempPositon variable to store the position of last clicked item. And try calling the **getview** method twice with the recently clicked item position and tempPositon one after another inside same method.

Comment: see here is the thing,i want multiple items to be selected,and highlighted ,this part works as expected but the problem is the first item also gets highlighted and i don't want it to happen

Comment: the first item gets highlighted automatically and i am unable to un-highlight it even though i can un-highlight the rest

Comment: need to see your whole code to check what is wrong then.. And if you are going to post code, post it after formatting properly.. Lots of space is very distracting. Would not be able map the code if there are many loops..

Comment: http://pastie.org/9230707

Comment: the relevant code is in line number 305

Comment: well very ugly work around,but i found a way...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you are not unchecking the previously clicked item. Keep of track of it with an int so that you can remove it when another item is selected.

Comment: okay.....your answer doesn't explain why the rest of items can be un-selected or un-highlighted but the problem arises with only the first item 
secondly why does the first item gets automatically highlighted ??

Comment: Sorry, I posted before you clarified that you were highlighting multiple views. Android recycles views in the ListView, this is probably the reason it is being highlighted each time

Comment: i think android only recycles the views when you specify it,and that's called view re usability which i am implementing by a view holder pattern 
and i don't think how this thing would cause  only the first item to be highlighted automatically ?

Comment: You need to post more of your code then, the first item must be getting checked automatically somewhere

Comment: What about your custom adapter?

Comment: And just to clarify, the first item is highlighted before you click any items? or only after you select one or more?

Comment: it is highlighted as soon as i select one or more,it is not highlighted before i click anything

Comment: Do post it as an answer, I have worked around the issue before but I cant find the article explaining it Im afraid